# android: connect to servlet

Tags: android, servlets, localhost, httpclient

I have to connect to server(servlet on tomcat) always running  and process the http request and send the response..

Client is Androbile mobile application.

I aware that I can connect using HTTP Client..

But to connect from device to server running on my PC...

I want to check if I can connect to my localhost from device...

Also if I want to use mobile network to connect from any android device on which this app is deployed.... Do I have to host this website(Server)...

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you have WiFi, simply join network and then in browser provide IP of your pc. As for wider accessibility, then yes you need to get host

Comment: Hi, I enabled WIFI and connected to my ISP.. But if I give http://ipaddr:8080/servletname its not connecting... same is connecting in my web browser on my laptop... I am getting ipaddr using ipconfig.. If I try to connect from android device it gived timeout error.. also if I try to open using internet from android device then also its fails... AM i doing anything wrong??

Comment: What I meant is wireless network. Do you have wirelees router, or you have just simple router without wireless?

Comment: Yes, I have a wireless router[my ISP].. so when I select WIFI option on android device I can see my wireless connection listed and I can connect to it... After that if I give http://192.168.1.105:8080/SimpleServlet/simple-servlet in the internet browser in android device it does not open... but the same opens on my laptop in the browser..

Comment: Hi, I was able to connect first time i tried, then it stopped working.. am nt sure if it was firewall problem... but it worked again.. So how do figure out if firewall is blocking. Also can we connect to localhost using mobile network(I tried but it doesn't connect")

Comment: You would not be able to access it from mobile network, because it is world wide network and your local host is not known.
As for local network issues, you can configure router and add mobile phone MAC address Settings/Wireless & networks/Wi-Fi Settings/Advanced (you need to press "Menu" to see this option). Use this MAC address in your router, assign a static IP on the network to this MAC address and then in firewall you just need to set/modify privileges for this static IP. Does it make sense?

Comment: Hi, yes it does.. So if I host my website any user wil be use it using android device using both WiFi and mobile network if I am nt wrong.. My usecase is user should be able to post request to server and server should send back the response. So I think the solution si to jost the server so that its in WWW. I hope my understanding is correct. Thanks for your help.